# SwiftUI: NavigationView bug in WatchOS 8.1 When List and ForEach is embedded in TabView

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, swiftui-navigationlink, watchos-8

The code below worked fine in WatchOS 7 and 8.0, but now in 8.1 tapping on the row will navigate to the destination but then immediately navigates back to the root view.

I filed Feedback #FB9727188 and included the below to demonstrate the issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {

 @State var tabIndex:Int = 0

    var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
            ListView()
                .tabItem { Group{
                    Text("List")
                }}.tag(0)
                .padding(.bottom, 1.0)
             Text("Second View")
                .tabItem { Group{
                    Text("Second")
                }}.tag(1)
            .padding(.bottom, 1.0)
             Text("Third View")
                .tabItem { Group{
                    Text("ThirdView")
                }}.tag(2)
           
        
            
        }
    }
}


struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
         List {
            ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) {_ in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("test")) {
                    Text("Tap Me but we'll just be back here")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663736/swiftui-navigationlink-pops-out-immediately-on-watchos-8-1rc-in-tabview related. Also seeing this in a project.

Comment: Do you have a public link to the Apple feedback?

Comment: @BradMartin can you see it? https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9727188

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue with watchOS 8.1 (and 8.3 beta) while it was working with previous watchOS versions.

We were able to get it working again by moving the `NavigationView` inside the `TabView`.
This workaround isn't ideal at all but it does seem to work.

```
@State private var tabSelection = 1

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            NavigationView {
                // List goes here
            }
            .tag(1)
            
            VStack {
                // content 2nd tab: we didn't have a list in the 2nd tab
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

However, there are 2 things impacted with this fix:

- I didn't get the `navigationBarTitle` working, so there won't be a title on top of the screen.
- If you click on an item in the list, it will navigate to your page (as expected) but the TabView dots at the bottom of the screen will remain.

Comment: Thanks yes not an ideal solution but thanks for the tip.  Did you file a Feedback?

Comment: @GarySabo I didn't file a feedback ticket. Do you think it would help if I do submit an extra ticket?

Comment: yes!! The more Feedbacks the higher priority it will get internally.  Especially for something only in WatchOS which doesn't get as much attention as iOS. I included a demo project that easily shows the issue.